# How to have columns of equal height in tcbcolorbox/ tcbraster

Tags: tcolorbox

Despite some distinct commands my boxes just deny to agree on the same height. Here's the clear code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, sharp corners, 
            raster equal height, raster column skip=-0.5mm]
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill, colback=blue!30, width = 0.3\textwidth,title = Title]
Column1 \\ \\
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
Column2 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

Despite of the *height fill* it appears to me the boxes are not grounded but rather offset

**Edit** I also figured compiling twice fixes the height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,size=small,
        colback=gray!15,colframe=cyan!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title=Box with 2 columns,bottom=2mm]    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,size=small,
    colback=gray!15,colframe=cyan!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Box with 3 columns,bottom=1mm]    
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \lipsum[3-5]
    \end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]